# How do i use Dialogflow V2 API in my spring boot application? I have successfully implemented it using V1 API

Tags: dialogflow-es

Okay so i have created a chatbot in ionic that makes GET request to my spring boot application. My spring boot application makes an API call to Dialogflow using the RestTemplate exchange method. I have successfully implemented it for V1 API. But for V2 integration the token expires in 1 hour. So i did some research and found out that i had to set up a secure account and follow the process and gcloud would give me the new token(After executing it in terminal and made an API call using postman). But i am unable to use this command in eclipse. I get the error ==> The Application Default Credentials are not available. They are available if running in Google Compute Engine. Otherwise, the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS must be defined pointing to a file defining the credentials.

I tried it by installing the google cloud SDK followed the documentation steps but it was of no help.

I even tried it with the GoogleCredential dependency but i could not get the access token (got it as null).

Any help would be appreciated.

Edit.

Have answered the question below.

Comment: The best way for you is to use the `GoogleCredential` method, but it isn't clear how you're trying to use it or what you might be doing. Can you update your question to include the code you're trying to use, any logs or debugging, etc?

Comment: thanks for your reply. I have found a solution and have added the solution to my question

Comment: If you have found a solution that works, go ahead and post it as an answer rather than as an update to the question. This way people will understand it is a solution.

Comment: Done and Done.......

Answer (score 0):

You can check the following [Java API for V2](https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-java-client-v2). I have used it in my Android app. [Here](https://medium.com/@abhi007tyagi/android-chatbot-with-dialogflow-8c0dcc8d8018), I have explained how to integrate into Android. You can follow this and modify for use with Spring. I am sure it will work.

Comment: okay thank you fro your answer but as mentioned my app is in ionic. How ever i was able to implement it in my spring boot application using command ==> gcloud auth application-default print-access-token. You will have to set up gcloud on your system. Steps for the setup can be found in the Dialogflow documentation. After setup run this command like in the terminal and it will provide u an updated token everytime. Code snippet to run the command in spring boot application cn be found above.

Comment: Thanks for the info 

Answer (score 0):

I was able to implement it in my spring boot application using command ==> gcloud auth application-default print-access-token. You will have to set up gcloud on your system. Steps for the setup can be found in the Dialogflow documentation. After setup run this command like in the terminal and it will provide u an updated token everytime.

Solution for the above problem :

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
String[] commands = { "gcloud command here" };
Process proc = rt.exec(commands);
proc.waitFor();
BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));
        BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getErrorStream()));

        String updatedAccesssToken = null;
        while ((updatedAccesssToken = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
            log.info("Updated access token :" + updatedAccesssToken);
            return updatedAccesssToken;
        }
        while ((updatedAccesssToken = stdError.readLine()) != null) {
            log.info("Error while fetching access token");
        }
```

Note : Add the json file in the resource folder. In run configuration set environment variable as Name : GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS and value : path to file